# How to convert Encrypted password into Plain text using sql hasher password in c# identity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, identity

I have existing website in old .net  membership approach, now what i wants to do is convert into new mvc **.net identity approach**

I have referred this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity),also i got the db converted into new identity db which is all works perfectly.

but the **problem is new identity is not working with my old password**.i.e while i am trying to login with my password its giving me error that password is incorrect.

***Edit : Added codes***

**Here is Application User manager code**

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
            : base(store)
        {
        }

        //Added this constructor after reading microsoft blog https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity.
        //except this constructor other codes are default which identity provides
        public ApplicationUserManager()
            : base(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()))
        {
            this.PasswordHasher = new SqlPasswordHasher();
        }

        public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
            // Configure validation logic for usernames
            manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };

            // Configure validation logic for passwords
            manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = 6,
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
                RequireDigit = true,
                RequireLowercase = true,
                RequireUppercase = true,
            };

            // Configure user lockout defaults
            manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
            manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

            // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
            // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                Subject = "Security Code",
                BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });
            manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
            manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
            var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
            if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
            {
                manager.UserTokenProvider =
                    new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
            }
            return manager;
        }
    }
```

Here is my **SQL Password Hasher** code.

```
 public class SqlPasswordHasher : PasswordHasher
    {
        public override string HashPassword(string password)
        {
            return base.HashPassword(password);
        }

        public override PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)
        {
            string[] passwordProperties = hashedPassword.Split('|');
            if (passwordProperties.Length != 3)
            {
                return base.VerifyHashedPassword(hashedPassword, providedPassword);
            }
            else
            {
                string passwordHash = passwordProperties[0];
                int passwordformat = 1;
                string salt = passwordProperties[2];
                if (String.Equals(EncryptPassword(providedPassword, passwordformat, salt), passwordHash, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    return PasswordVerificationResult.SuccessRehashNeeded;
                }
                else
                {
                    return PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
                }
            }
        }

        //This is copied from the existing SQL providers and is provided only for back-compat.
        private string EncryptPassword(string pass, int passwordFormat, string salt)
        {
            if (passwordFormat == 0) // MembershipPasswordFormat.Clear
                return pass;

            byte[] bIn = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);
            byte[] bSalt = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
            byte[] bRet = null;

            if (passwordFormat == 1)
            { // MembershipPasswordFormat.Hashed 
                HashAlgorithm hm = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1");
                if (hm is KeyedHashAlgorithm)
                {
                    KeyedHashAlgorithm kha = (KeyedHashAlgorithm)hm;
                    if (kha.Key.Length == bSalt.Length)
                    {
                        kha.Key = bSalt;
                    }
                    else if (kha.Key.Length < bSalt.Length)
                    {
                        byte[] bKey = new byte[kha.Key.Length];
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(bSalt, 0, bKey, 0, bKey.Length);
                        kha.Key = bKey;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        byte[] bKey = new byte[kha.Key.Length];
                        for (int iter = 0; iter < bKey.Length;)
                        {
                            int len = Math.Min(bSalt.Length, bKey.Length - iter);
                            Buffer.BlockCopy(bSalt, 0, bKey, iter, len);
                            iter += len;
                        }
                        kha.Key = bKey;
                    }
                    bRet = kha.ComputeHash(bIn);
                }
                else
                {
                    byte[] bAll = new byte[bSalt.Length + bIn.Length];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(bSalt, 0, bAll, 0, bSalt.Length);
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(bIn, 0, bAll, bSalt.Length, bIn.Length);
                    bRet = hm.ComputeHash(bAll);
                }
            }

            return Convert.ToBase64String(bRet);
        }
    }
```

**Here is Login Method in account controller**

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
            }
        }
```

Appreciate your help !!!

Comment: you need to provide a lot more information than this

Comment: @Bearded updated post and added code.please let me know if more you needed.

Comment: Did you use `SqlPasswordHasher` with membership as well?

Comment: @alisson  my old website was in .net membership but i didnt used sql hashed password, only used default membership approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I got solution of my own question.added new method for converting encrypted password into plain text.**

Problem was in membership tables password are stored in encrypted format,so we needs to implement method which can convert encrypted password into plain text.which is as follow

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Security;
namespace GS365.MVC.Helpers
{
    public class SQLPasswordHasher : PasswordHasher
    {
        public override string HashPassword(string password)
        {
            return base.HashPassword(password);
        }

        public override PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)
        {
            string[] passwordProperties = hashedPassword.Split('|');
            if (passwordProperties.Length != 3)
            {
                return base.VerifyHashedPassword(hashedPassword, providedPassword);
            }
            else
            {
                string password = passwordProperties[0];
                int passwordformat = Convert.ToInt16(passwordProperties[1]);
                if (passwordformat == 0 || passwordformat == 1) //Password type :0=Clear and 1=Hashed
                {
                    string salt = passwordProperties[2];
                    if (String.Equals(EncryptPassword(providedPassword, passwordformat, salt), password, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        return PasswordVerificationResult.SuccessRehashNeeded;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
                    }
                }
                else if (passwordformat == 2)//Password type : 2=Encrypted
                {
                    SqlMembershipProviderHelper sqlmembershipproviderhelper = new SqlMembershipProviderHelper();
                    var existingPassword = sqlmembershipproviderhelper.GetClearTextPassword(password);
                    if (String.Equals(existingPassword, providedPassword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        return PasswordVerificationResult.SuccessRehashNeeded;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
                    }
                }
                return PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
            }
        }

        //This is copied from the existing SQL providers and is provided only for back-compat.
        private string EncryptPassword(string pass, int passwordFormat, string salt)
        {
            if (passwordFormat == 0) // MembershipPasswordFormat.Clear
                return pass;

            byte[] bIn = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);
            byte[] bSalt = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
            byte[] bRet = null;

            if (passwordFormat == 1)
            { // MembershipPasswordFormat.Hashed 
                HashAlgorithm hm = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1");
                if (hm is KeyedHashAlgorithm)
                {
                    KeyedHashAlgorithm kha = (KeyedHashAlgorithm)hm;
                    if (kha.Key.Length == bSalt.Length)
                    {
                        kha.Key = bSalt;
                    }
                    else if (kha.Key.Length < bSalt.Length)
                    {
                        byte[] bKey = new byte[kha.Key.Length];
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(bSalt, 0, bKey, 0, bKey.Length);
                        kha.Key = bKey;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        byte[] bKey = new byte[kha.Key.Length];
                        for (int iter = 0; iter < bKey.Length;)
                        {
                            int len = Math.Min(bSalt.Length, bKey.Length - iter);
                            Buffer.BlockCopy(bSalt, 0, bKey, iter, len);
                            iter += len;
                        }
                        kha.Key = bKey;
                    }
                    bRet = kha.ComputeHash(bIn);
                }
                else
                {
                    byte[] bAll = new byte[bSalt.Length + bIn.Length];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(bSalt, 0, bAll, 0, bSalt.Length);
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(bIn, 0, bAll, bSalt.Length, bIn.Length);
                    bRet = hm.ComputeHash(bAll);
                }
            }
            return Convert.ToBase64String(bRet);
        }
    }

    public class SqlMembershipProviderHelper : SqlMembershipProvider
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Used for decrypt password into plain text from encrypted type password
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="encryptedPwd"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string GetClearTextPassword(string encryptedPwd)
        {
            byte[] encodedPassword = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedPwd);
            byte[] bytes = this.DecryptPassword(encodedPassword);
            if (bytes == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes, 0x10, bytes.Length - 0x10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, Can you please tell how did you get the password format and the salt?